# Simple door sensor with notifications suggestions

Tags: home-automation

I recently came across a guide for using a reed switch and a simple chat program to notify and keep track of the opening and closing of a door. I would like to get similar functionality plus webcam photos but I'm not sure what the best option would be.

Twitter seems like a simple solution to receive notification and post photos.

HangoutsBot is a bit more involved but is interesting.

SMS could also work but is a bit older.

Rocket.Chat is the one made through the original guide here https://blog.haschek.at/post/f31aa

I am planning on putting the reed switch on a closet door that has my photography equipment stored there. No one else really should be opening or closing that closet in this house except for me. Ideally I would be notified and have a photo taken (via the official pi camera) that I could see the culprit in action.

Are there any other options that would be a simple solution to this task?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

PS On the guide linked above they use a 10k ohm resistor for the reed switch whereas the adafruit guide for using a reed switch recommends using the Pi's internal pull-up resistor. Is there any other information I could read on this? I'm feeling a bit out of my depth.
I did find this link: [Do I need a current limiting resistor in series with a magnetic door sensor?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28973/do-i-need-a-current-limiting-resistor-in-series-with-a-magnetic-door-sensor) and it seems that putting a 10k ohm resistor might be good for protecting the longevity of the reed switch?