# Trouble coding test program to turn LED on and off

Tags: gpio, pi-pico-w

I'm trying to code a button to turn and LED on and off.

```
from machine import Pin

led = Pin(16, Pin.OUT)
button = Pin(17, Pin.IN)


while True:
    if button.value()==1:
        led.high()
        print("hello")
    if button.value()==0:
        led.low()
```

This is all running on a Pi Pico W. I notice the LED turns on anytime a wire is connected to pin 17, even if the wire isn't plugged into anything else. When I push the button it lights up brighter, and prints Hello.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why do you believe that the problem is  caused by the code? ... please add all of the available information to your question

Comment: Post a photo of your wiring. I assume your button is connected to 3.3V, you should pull down your input. https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-pico/6

Answer (score 1):

It may be a case of floating pin. Try inserting a (for example) 10k resistor between the pin and GND. [How do pull-down resistors work?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54951/how-do-pull-down-resistors-work)

Comment: Or just configure pull down on the pin.